# How to get query string in koa with koa-bodyparser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, koa

app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(route.get('/objects/', objects.all));
```

objects.js

```
module.exports.all = function * all(next) {
  this.body = yield objects.find({});
};
```

This works fine for get all objects. But I wanna get by query param, something like this localhost:3000/objects?city=Toronto How to use "city=Toronto" in my objects.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `this.query` to access all your query parameters.

For example, if the request came at the url `/objects?city=Toronto&color=green` you would get the following:

```
function * routeHandler (next) {
  console.log(this.query.city) // 'Toronto'
  console.log(this.query.color) // 'green'
}
```

If you want access to the entire querystring, you can use `this.querystring` instead. You can read more about it in the [docs](http://koajs.com/#context).

---

Edit: With Koa v2, you would use `ctx.query` instead of `this.query`.